# What is a good card creating application?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation

Is there a good card creating application? Haven't had one in over ten years but used to have one that had all types of easy to use templates designs etc for ton of occasions. Looking for something that can fill this void and do everything from Christmas cards to greeting cards and get well cards. I know this is possible in Gimp/Scribus but I'm looking for something less involved

Comment: +1! While trying to replace Windows with Ubuntu, I'd also need to find a replacement for MS Publisher.

Answer (score 2):

I found these templates online for LibreOffice:
http://templates.services.openoffice.org/en/search/node/greeting%20card

Answer (score 1):

You can try [glabels](http://packages.ubuntu.com/glabels) [image: Install glabels], it has a large number of templates for things such as this.