# Is there a greeting card maker?

Tags: software-recommendation, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good card creating application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26239/what-is-a-good-card-creating-application)

Is there any software for creating great Greeting Cards in Ubuntu? Maybe the question has been asked before, but I didn't find scribus or GIMP suitable. Is there any specific application for creating Greeting Cards?

Comment: Hi RP. Welcome to this site. You don't need to mention ubuntu in the title of your question (before my edit) as that is fairly obvious. You should also try to make it a real question. As such it is likely to be answered more quickly.

Comment: scribus is the way to go. Tutorial/how to:http://www.tuxmagazine.com/node/1000035